# illegalAccessError while using chromedriver with selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting IllegalAccessError while using chromedriver in selenium. I have added chromedriver.exe to my path, and also set it in java code. here is my code

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/Users/me/Documents/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe");
 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

here is the console output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(Ljava/io/File;)V from class org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:39)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.usingDriverExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:104)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:72)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:107)
```

I have also tried running the chromedriver.exe and then executing the code, still getting the error.

Comment: Are you running it as an administrator?

Comment: got the same with the phantomjsdriver

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by using an older version of selenium, where the checkExecutable method was still private